# Jquery asynchrone requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have implemented comet client in jquery as following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    comet();
});

function comet(){
    var cometJSON = {
            'comet': 'id'
        }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/comet",
        data: JSON.stringify(cometJSON),
        async: true, /* Set async request*/
        cache: false,
        timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

        success: function(data){ 
            console.log('suc');
            eventReceived(data); 

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("error: "+textStatus);

        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            console.log("Send new comet!");
            comet();
        }
    });
};
```

Everything works fine, but I have always noisy spinner in my browser tab and my status pannel always shows: Waiting for localhost, how can I fix that?

Comment: you don't need to `JSON.stringify` your `data` parameter - it expects a javascript object

Comment: I need a string at server side

Comment: If you are using Chrome or Firefox+Firebug (for example), check the JavaScript console for errors. Is the page in the question hosted by the same server you are making the AJAX post to? If you have loaded the page locally you might be hitting a security issue with [Cross-domain XMLHTTPRequests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests)

Comment: My javascript console is clean as a whistle, cross-domains problems were fixed with setting header Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spinner indicates a connection in progress, which is exactly what is happening - after you receive an answer, in `complete` section you instantly trigger a new request, hence there is a connection in progress most of the time (pretty much always). To avoid it, you need to do a delay before a new request - `setTimeout(comet, 1000)` sounds like a good alternative to the last `comet();`

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the same thing a while back and ran into the same problem:

https://github.com/tenorviol/cometjax

To solve the problem of the forever spinner, put a timeout on your initial ajax call, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
    comet();
  }, 10);
});
```